# What language is an android app like twodots using?

Tags: android

Noob here.  Android apps are written in Java. An app like twodots doesn't look like typical Java. What language are they using to make their list of levels?

It almost looks like they made it in flash but you don't need Adobe Air so I'm assuming they didn't.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you at least post a link to that app, which only you are familiar with?

Comment: Why not simply write an email to the developer and ask? In google play store there must be a contact address. Maybe you have luck and the developer will answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code monkey got it right.

Emailing the developer answered this question quickly.

Reply from developer:

Thanks for the compliments. The Android version of TwoDots was created in Unity using Objective C/C#.

Thanks!